# Which collider should i use and why to use it?

Tags: unity-game-engine, scripting

My ideia basically is when i score i get 2 points, but when i touch a certain collider that changes to 3 and i am having a lot a trouble figuring out what colliders to use and how to use them.

I thnik i need to use another ontriggerenter

when i touch the cube it should change to 3

[image]

```
if (i touch a certain collider)
{
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        ScoringSystem.theScore += 3;
    }
}
else 
{
    ScoringSystem.theScore += 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all we need to create a GameManager to handle the Bool that checks if we are currently on the Line or not. We do this so we can acces it from all the scripts.

This code should be in a GameManager Object.

```
// Variable to check if the player is on the line or not
public bool stayingOnLine = false;

#region Singelton
public static GameManager instance;

void Awake()
{
    if (instance != null) {
        Debug.LogWarning("More than one Instance of GameManager found");
        return;
    }

    instance = this;
}
#endregion
```

Then we add this Code to the GameObject that handles the LineCollider, to handle when the player enters the Line and when he leaves it. When this happens we change the Varible from the GameManager.

This code should be in your GameObject where the LineCollider  that is set to IsTrigger is located.

```
GameManager gm;

void Start() {
        gm = GameManager.instance;
}
    
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col) {
    // Player has entered the Line ColliderBox
    if (col.CompareTag("Player Tag"))
        gm.stayingOnLine = true;
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider col) {
    // Player has left the Line ColliderBox
    if (col.CompareTag("Player Tag"))
        gm.stayingOnLine = false;
}
```

After that we also need to add code to the GameObject that manages the HoopCollider. Because when the Ball enters we need to check if stayingOnline is true or false and then give different amount of points.

```
GameManager gm;

void Start() {
        gm = GameManager.instance;
}
    
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col) {
    // Ball has entered the Hoop ColliderBox
    if (!col.CompareTag("Ball Tag"))
        return;
    
    if (gm.stayingOnLine)
       ScoringSystem.theScore += 3;
    else
       ScoringSystem.theScore += 2;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216801/discussion-on-answer-by-mathewhd-which-collider-should-i-use-and-why-to-use-it).